# Is multithreading a part of Queue contract?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

Currently I have an algorithm which somewhat looks like web-spiders or file search systems - it has a collection of the elements to process and processing elements can lead to enqueuing more elements.

However this algorithm is single threaded - it's because I fetch data from the db and would like to have only single db connection at once.
In my current situation performance is not critical - I'm doing this only for the visualization purposes to ease up debugging.

For me it seems natural to use queue abstraction, however it's seems that using queues implies multithreading - as I understand, most of standard java queue implementations reside in java.util.concurrent package.

[image: list of Queue interface implementations]

I understand that I can go on with any data structure that support *pull* and *push* but I would like to know what data structure is more natural to use in this case(is it ok to use a queue in a single threaded application?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue is defined in java.util. LinkedList is a Queue and not very concurrency-friendly. None of the Queue method blocks, so they should be safe from a single threaded perspective.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically fine to use the `java.util.concurrent` structures with a single thread.

The main thing to watch out for is blocking calls. If you use a bounded-size structure like an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), and you call the [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29) method on a queue that's full, then the calling thread will block until there is space in the queue. If you use any kind of queue and you call [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) when it's empty, the calling thread will block until there's something in the queue. If you application is single-threaded, than those things can never happen, so that means blocking forever.

To avoid `put` blocking, you could use an unbounded structure like a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). To avoid blocking on removal, use a non-blocking operation - [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) throws an exception if the queue is empty, and [`poll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) returns null.

Having said that, there are implementations of the [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface that are not in `java.util.concurrent`. [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) would probably be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to use any queue in a single threaded application. Synchronization overhead, in absence of concurrent threads, should be negligible, and is noticeable only if element processing time is very short.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Queue with a ThreadPool I sugges using an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) which combines both for you.  The ExecutorService use LinkedBlockingQueue by default.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

http://recursor.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/mini-executorservice-future-how-to-for.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html